# secure authentication in Nuxt3

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am implementing an app using Nuxt3 and Firebase.
Currently, the authentication is using a plugin. The problem is that to define firebase tools in the plugin I have to use a public variable containing the API keys etc ... So everything looks to be visible into the client side.

I am looking for a secure way to implement auth on the server-side. How can I proceed to avoid any problem ?

Thanks for help

Comment: I think this [VueFire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/) can help you. But it's in the early development stage. And you can use `firebase-admin-sdk` to implement nuxt ssr auth

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned that your `firebaseConfig` is exposed on the client side, that's fine.

As answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public) thread, that config simply identifies it on the firebase server.